# using 'and' / 'or 'inside while structure

Tags: python

I wrote this code and got a little bit confused at the 'while' part.

```
[while (sexo != 'M' and sexo!='F'):]
```

I wanted to show this phrase if the variable sexo was different from M or F. I used 'or' but it only worked when I used 'and'. Can anyone explain it to me why it is working this way?

Here is the full code:

```
repetir='Sim'

while repetir=='Sim':
    nome =input('Digite seu nome: ')
    sexo=input("Digite 'M' se pertencer ao sexo masculino ou 'F' se pertencer ao sexo feminino.\n")


    while (sexo != 'M' and sexo!='F'):
            sexo=input('Você não é um plateominto.Digite essa zorra correta!\n')


    if sexo=='M':
            print('O nome dele é %s.' %(nome))
    else :
            print('O nome dela é %s.' %(nome))
    repetir=input('Deseja repetir operação?\n' )
```

Comment: Read it out loud: "while `sexo` is not M and `sexo` is not F..."

Answer (score 0):

The full code is not visible (at least, on my computer it says "Blockquote").

Anyway, with the "and" condition, you are requesting to input a gender that is either M or F. Since the user inputs a value that is different from the two, then you keep asking for a gender. Basically, you are saying: "until you gender is not M nor F, then I keep asking you the gender".

The code inside the loop will repeat until the condition between brackets is met. Try writing down a table of all possible combinations, when the input is M, F or else (for the latter just one letter like A is enough) and try to evaluate step by step the condition